# Why dont any queries get run when using linq after upgrading to nhibernate 3.0

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

i was using nhibernate 2.1 and the linq provider.  i had the following code:

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>()
{
     return Session.Linq<T>();
}
```

which would allow me to run queries like this:

```
IEnumerable<Picture> pictures = Query<Picture>();
```

i just upgraded to nhibernate 3.0 (which seems to have more mature linq functionality) and this code

```
Session.Linq<T>
```

doesn't compile

i tried replacing it with:

```
Session.Query<T>
```

which compiled but all my queries now return 0 records.

can anyone help explain to me the upgrade path for this and if i am doing something wrong?  based on [this post](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html), this syntax should work but always seems to return 0 records.

### NOTE:

Some additional info:  I just ran nhibernate profiler and it detects the session but it doesn't show any SQL queries being run.  Is there any reason that anyone can think of that would not have this run any query??

Comment: Your 'NH3.0' Query isn't right, you have a single = so you're doing assignment but condition.

Comment: @Phill - that was just a typo in the question. i have fixed this. I actually removed the where clause as i dont get any records even if i dont have any where clause.  Even just Query<Picture> provides no results

Comment: By changing Linq to Query, your queries should work just fine.

Comment: @Phill - hmm ..  it must be something else then but this is the only line of code i changed (along with just updating the references to the new dlls)

Comment: Did you drop out ALL the related NH assemblies and reference the new ones? Run up profiler and grab the query thats being executed.

Comment: Are you able to execute any queries, even a non-LINQ one - just to make sure NH can actually talk to your DB.

Comment: @Phill - i definately have all of the new references. I ran the nhibernate profiler and it doesn't show any SQL queries being run. it detects the session but no queries run. any thoughts??

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with the query. I mean if you do: Session.Query<Picture>().ToList(); does it execute the query. (checking make sure it's not deferred execution throwing you off)

Comment: @Phill - its not deferred execution as i am trying to take the results of the query and output them to a webpage. Remember, this all worked fine in nhibernate 2.1 and the 1.0 linq.  As mentioned by Will, i am going to try with the regular nhibernate syntax (not linq) and see if that works.

Comment: Haha, I'm trying man, clutching at straws. I wish I could team view you so i could take a look, i'm using the NH3.0 build from Fluent NHibernate website without any issues right now. Tho it's almost 1am i need to go to sleep. I'm thinking there must be a reference missing or not updating properly somewhere. Don't think it's your code, just a silly pebkac problem.

Comment: @Will Hughes - i tried using this syntax to remove linq from the equation:  Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>().AsQueryable() and that returned no results as well

Comment: @Phill - thanks for the effort here ;).  As mentioned in the above comment to Will. even the CreateCriteria syntax doesn't seem to be working.  Definately don't stay up any later on my account (while i do appreciate the effort).  i am going to remove and add the references again and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ooo Weird. ok, silliness check: Does 2.1 work if you put the old DLLs back.

Comment: When you re-add the references, do a solution clean too. I must go sleep now, I like problem solving, good fun :) sorry I can't fix it tho.

Comment: @Will Hughes - as you suggest. i will try to revert to 2.1 and see if it works . . will let you know in 3 mins

Comment: @Will Hughes - revered back to old nhibernate, fluent nhibernate, nhibernate.linq, etc and changed the 1 line of code from .Query<T> back to .Linq<T> and everything works fine on the old version . . does this help confirm anything for why the new version may not work ??

Comment: Did you download the GA release (NHibernate-3.0.0.GA-bin), maybe you've inadvertently downloaded the CR release (NHibernate-3.0.0.CR1-bin). Try GA

Comment: Not necessarily Linq of NHibernate, *maybe* there are some components that are incompatible to framework version. I encounter error on Linq(System.Linq only) if I'm using Mono version 4.0; when on Mono 3.5, things just work well. http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/troubleshooting-nunit-testing-of-linq.html

Comment: @Phill, @Will Hughes  - i figured it out . . apparently there was a post build script that was recopying over the 2.1 versions of nhibernate back into the bin directory . .aaaaaahhh :)..  thanks for your help

Comment: Haha, I knew it was something to do with references :D Just wasn't sure what. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The issue was a post build event that was running a script to copy the old version of nhibernate back to the bin directory

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect IEnumerable pictures = Session.Query(); to execute some sql, because an enumerable is declared, but not executed. IEnumerable pictures = Session.Query().ToList(); will execute sql.

Comment: are you simply referring to delayed execution.  If so, i am taking the pictures results and printing them out on a webpage so i would expect that to cause the SQL to be triggered.  As stated it doesn't as when i look at the list, it contains no results . . .  in addition (also stated in the comments, when i changed to the code to do this:  Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>().AsQueryable(), it also returned no results.  As stated all of this works fine in nhibernate 2.1 . . .